# Filter [springSecurityFilterChain]: could not be initialized

Tags: spring, spring-security, websphere-liberty

For the first time, my program looks great, everything is working on the web, web-server is up and running. 
But then I got this error during the run-time after I edited my existing code for the second time  (even just editing string's value gives me this error):

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0321E: The [springSecurityFilterChain] filter did not load during start up.
Filter [springSecurityFilterChain]: could not be initialized
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [springSecurityFilterChain]: could not be initialized
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:158)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [springSecurityFilterChain]: could not be initialized
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:641)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:324)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:144)
    ... 1 more
```

But after I clean both the web server and project, with did maven update. This error seems to go away. Any clue as to why this is happening?

Inside both my applicationContext config file and web.xml I declared a bean for spring security filter, so everything should be working fine there.

Comment: Can you add your applicationContext configuration? do you included spring-security.

Answer (score 4):

I finally solved my own problem! This kind of error is tricky.

Since I am using eclipse, this is the case for me.
Every time I had my server running while editing a piece of code. Then when I hit the save button, my server automatically rerun's itself at the background, however I wasn't paying attention to this as I inexpertly hit the save button and run the server again. (Meanwhile, the server and the document are trying to render at the background)

Perhaps my computer isn't fast enough or something, it just keeps giving me that error message.

What I did is the following step.
Clean the server -> Maven Build -> Update Project -> Maven Build -> Rerun the server -> (Yeah! It's working again)

Word of advice: Stop your server before editing your code! LOL

Answer (score 0):

The above solution I have tried but seems like I still have issues.

I have solved the problem  by following steps.

Go to your Project -> right click on project -> Go to Maven -> Disable Workspace Resolution

Rebuild the application. It solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while upgrading dependencies. What worked for me was to remove the war from the Tomcat server and clean the Tomcat directory (Note I am using Tomcat 9 and the latest Eclipse as of 2022). Again rebuild the project and add it to tomcat and restarted the tomcat. Bingo.....